# Let Cassandra dynamically publish on a Kafka topic using a connector

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

So I have this Kafka topic which receives data from an external source, and writes it to a Cassandra table (through a sink connector).

In the Cassandra table, I have data in this format:

```
[
 SessionID varchar,
 TS timestamp,
 TYPE varchar,
 other data...
]
```

with `SessionID` as the partition key, and `(TS, TYPE)` as the clustering key.

So my goal is to be able to "replay" any session that's existed (currently live or not). To do that, I need to retrieve the corresponding session's data from Cassandra (ie. `WHERE SessionID=XXX`) and let Cassandra publish the query result on a Kafka topic.

To solve that, I am trying to use a source connector between Cassandra and Kafka (if there is a better way, please tell me about it). This connector allows for a KCQL query, which is "fixed" when the connector starts.

So the problem is: Is there a way to change the KCQL query over time to ask for a different SessionID, or should I create a new, automatically generated, connector every time I want to stream a different session ?

Thanks!

Comment: why not write a really simple java or python program that will read data from cassandra and push to Kafka? Having Kafka Connect is overkill imho...

Comment: I was indeed thinking about doing a small script for this. Concerning the real time streaming from Cassandra, do you think this is a viable option ?

Comment: Right now there is no real option for real-time streaming from Cassandra. There is a CDC option, but it has a lot of limitations, and quite complex to implement. Depending on the size of data, and size of cluster, and query patterns, Spark could be a viable option, if for example, if you'll want periodically push "new" sessions (for example, sessions since some time)